# ACHI port 0 device error

Tags: windows-7, windows

We had high winds early this morning and several power outages.  I have a back up battery back up on our PC's, but my wife decided to turn off the PC's after several outages.  When I try to boot my Win 7 64 machine I get Nothing.  When I hit recovery, I get ACHI port 0 device error.  Attempting to boot normally or boot to last known configuration after that does nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: You say many times that you "get nothing" or that it "does nothing", but that's a totally unhelpful description. Does that mean you don't even get a BIOS screen? Or that the boot process hangs? (And if so, where?) Or that you get an error message? (And if so, what message?)

Answer (score 0):

That error is usually a sign of hard drive failure. Use the hard drive manufacturers diagnostics on the drive to see if it is toast.